# What's the difference between the different "frame guides" in New Pokémon Snap?

Tags: new-pokemon-snap

In the options, I can change "frame guide" to *"Full"*, *"Normal"*, or *"Simple"*. What does this mean? What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options normal, simple, and full affect the camera’s frame border while on the maps. The borders help assist you visually to see where the Pokémon will appear in the photo

*Normal Frame* - Default, single frame border
[image: Normal frame]

*Simple Frame* - No frame border
[image: Simple Frame]

*Full Frame* - Double frame border
[image: full frame]